# How do I handle multiple arguments with `hook_drush_command()`?

Tags: drush

I have to implement a drush command with multiple arguments. How should I handle them  in `hook_drush_command()`?

Comment: Please add the code you've already tried, what didn't work, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'official' `make-me-a-sandwich` command:

```
function sandwich_drush_command() {
  $items = array();

  // The 'make-me-a-sandwich' command
  $items['make-me-a-sandwich'] = array(
    'arguments' => array(
      'filling' => 'The type of the sandwich (turkey, cheese, etc.). Defaults to ascii.',
    ),
  );
}
```

Arguments is clearly an array. Add new keys to it.

Comment: function sandwich_drush_command() {
  $items = array();

  // The 'make-me-a-sandwich' command
  $items['make-me-a-sandwich'] = array(
    'arguments' => array(
      'filling' => 'The type of the sandwich (turkey, cheese, etc.). Defaults to ascii.',
    ),
  );
}